# Why is it that only light aircraft are equipped with airframe parachutes?

Tags: parachute, airframe, airframe-parachute

Why is it that only light aircraft (like Cessnas and Cirrus') are equipped with airframe parachutes? Isn't it possible for at least slightly larger aircraft to have this feature? And isn't there a way to recover the fuselage of a relatively larger aircraft?

Comment: @Federico, while that question talks about _much_ larger aircraft, and this one specifies _slightly_ larger aircraft, I'd agree that most of the reasoning there is applicable.

Comment: @FreeMan then there is this one: [Why don't all new GA planes include a parachute system?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/593)

Comment: FYI the situations in which an airframe parachute would be useful are very rare and the probability does not justify the loss in cargo capacity.

Comment: Bah! RedGrittyBrick got in on the voting and messed up our alliteration in F!  :/